# Why does Bender always say his name after he refers to himself?

Tags: futurama

Why does Bender always say his name after he refers to himself? ex. (Fry old buddy it's me, Bender.)

Comment: Perhaps he doesn't understand humans have facial recognition.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: Well, there are other [model #22 bending units](http://theinfosphere.org/Bending_Units). ;)

Comment: "It's me, <my name>." is a common english phrase.  Often heard over the phone.

Answer (score 11):

I see two possible explanations:

1. Bender isn't the only model #22 [bending unit](http://theinfosphere.org/Bending_Units). There's also [Flexo](http://theinfosphere.org/Flexo) and [Billy West](http://theinfosphere.org/Billy_West_%28robot%29), and potentially many others who look like him. Maybe he's trying to clear up any confusion that may cause.
2. Bender is all about name recognition, and will do just about anything to be famous/remembered (see episode ["A Pharaoh to Remember"](http://theinfosphere.org/A_Pharaoh_to_Remember), among many others). He likes to repeat his name ([and greatness](http://theinfosphere.org/Bender_is_great)) as often as possible:

   > Bender is great! Bender, Bender is great!

Answer (score 4):

Bender's ego is amazingly huge! The concept of he has about himself is closer to divinity, Bender thinks that everybody is a sucker and he is the 'Master of Puppets', life is a big game that he plays to win and others are the pawns... and it is true! ;) So talking of himself in third person gives to his words the importance he deserves.

Answer (score 0):

Bender suffers from a disassociative personality disorder so that like Nixon he can deny being associated with his questionable behaviour publicly, "I am not a crook" (Nixon), While continuing to reap the advantages of his aberrant actions privately. His assertion ie. "that was me - Bender" is an attempt to qualify the "real Bender" as an authentic personality thus giving him a feeling of self worth and in a way vindicating the "true" Bender versus his alter ego Bender.

Answer (score 0):

Because he's Bender and he's awesome and he knows it but he wants other people to know it. Whenever he says his name at the end of a sentence referring to himself he is drawing the attention to himself and making sure that people know that he's talking about him.... so they better listen.